# How to make a string[] from the words of a file in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, text, file

I have .txt file containing all the English words separated by line breaks.

I want to turn them to a string[] so I can easily pick a random one from them.

The way I would do that in normal C# is the File.ReadAllLines(path) function in the System.IO namespace.

But, I don't think that I can use System.IO with Unity so the alternative that I could come up with is the TextAsset class which I can use to reference an imported text asset and get its text property as a string.

But, if I have a giant string how can I simply split it up into individual words and store them as a string[]?

Comment: Why couldn't you use `System.IO`? Have you even tried? It's totally fine to use it.

Comment: Have you ever taken a look at a built Unity project? The Asset folder in the editor contains your files, but when you build your project all your assets get packed into weird package files. But, maybe I am not familiar enough with the System.IO class and you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split a string into substrings with [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx).

When you don't have any whitepsaces in that textfile but line breaks (as in no words with spaces in them) you can use

```
string[] words = yourTextAsset.text.Split();
```

When you do have whitespaces, use the solution from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net):

```
string[] words = yourTextAsset.text.Split(
    new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, 
    StringSplitOptions.None
);
```

(or instead of that hardcoded array with all kinds of line separator flavors, figure out which one is used in your text file)